# Orthogonality of filter impulse response to its even shift

Tags: dft, dtft, orthogonal-signals

I meet this problem but still do not know how to solve it.
Could you guy give me some guides?

Upsampling by 2 ($U_2$) followed by filtering by $g$, with operator $G$

And given: $<g_n,g_{n-2k}>_n = \delta_k$
(Filters with impulse responses orthogonal to their even shifts)

Prove that:
$$
I = U_2^*G^*GU_2
$$

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is clearly homework, let's help you with hints:

The set of  tricks for such problems is typically pretty limited; try (and that's really what solves the issue)

- Multiplying the equation with elements from your right-hand term from left and/or right, so that identity matrices form.
- Writing your matrix/operator property down as structure of your matrix
- applying transposes, and hermitians until things happen.

Comment: I just don't know what to do with: <,−2>=

Comment: The notation you're using is unfamiliar.  What is $\left < g_n,\,g_{n-2k} \right >_n = \delta_k$ supposed to mean?  If you don't know, there's your problem, and it should be in your book or the lecture notes.

Comment: @TimWescott I'd have said that these brackets signify the signal vector space inner product between an infinite sequence $g[n]$ and it's $2k$-shifted variant $g[n-2k]$. And that's always 0, unless $k=0$.